# Proper preposition with "gifted"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Gifted means talanted, but how to be more specific with the area, like 'art' ,'math'etc.

Can i say

> "she is gifted in art"?

Or

> "she is gifted with art"?

Or

> "she is gifted art"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it would usually be ***in*** or ***at***.

> She is gifted in art
>
> She is gifted at maths

There might be patterns of preferred use for particular things in which one might be gifted, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

'*Gifted with*' also turn up, but with a different structure. Then you use it to talk about someone's gifts as a conceptual (or actual) *thing*, a noun.

> He is gifted with a magnificent physique
>
> She is gifted with intelligence
>
> They are gifted with natural grace
>
> Zebras are gifted with long necks

With no preposition, you are talking about someone being given an actual gift.

> He was gifted a smart briefcase on graduation from law school
>
> She was gifted a beautiful necklace
>
> They were gifted twelve acres of land

However, note that all of those examples lacking a preposition can be rephrased to use *with*; they still refer to a gift that is given. Which is more natural will vary. In all cases, however, using "gifted" to mean "given a gift" is less used in most dialects I have come across. We would just say "given".

> She was gifted with a beautiful necklace
>
> She was given a beautiful necklace.

*Gifted* is now usually used to talk about "personal gifts", as in "gifted and talented youth", or the first two groups of examples in these answers.